# How can I save value in new table on editing one table? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save value in  directory_changes table while updating the value of directories table. I want this because I dont want it to save directly instead save it in different table and on admin approving it show it on live site .

```
def update
 @directory = Directory.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])

respond_to do |format|

if @directory.update_attributes(directory_params)

    @directory_changes = DirectoryChange.new(directory_change_params)
    format.html { redirect_to directories_path, :notice => 'Directory submitted for review', status: 301 }
  else
    format.html { render :action => :new }
  end
end
end

My view file looks like this 
= form_for(:directory_change, url: { action: :create }, :method => :post) do |f|
.form
.form-group
  = f.label :name, "Company name:"
  = f.text_field :name, :size => "30", :class => "form-control"
.form-group
  = f.label :abn, "ABN:"
  = f.text_field :abn, :size => "30", :class => "form-control"
```

Comment: yeah, its easy @directory_changes.save to save the directory_changes why are you struggling?what's your problem?

Comment: I am getting params missing for directory_changes error @giridharan

Comment: are you using the nested form can you share your view file?

Comment: No I am not using nested form.
I have 2 different params in directories controller, one directories params and another directory changes params.

Comment: I have pasted the view file in above code @giridharan

Comment: did you see the log? if the params come or not .use 'directory_change_params.inspect' to confirm

Comment: Did you define `directory_change_params` and how? Please show us? It should be defined in this controller and derive from the received/posted params. Show the log, it will show which params are posted and which params were rejected.